# Uncompress Image - Multiple out truncated SVD (Python)

Tags: python-3.x, pca, svd

I have been given the SVD representation of an image (Sigma, Uk, Vk) - I need to reconstruct the image by multiplying out the truncated SVD.

I have tried:
k = Uk.shape[1]
return (Uk * Sigma[:k]).dot(VkT)

I have also used np.diag to convert Sigma from a 1D array to a diagonal matrix.

Answer (score 0):

close..

```
Uk.dot(np.diag(Sigma[:k])).dot(VkT)
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, you can improve your answer by adding context or additional information to your solution. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer